Showing cors autharization error while trying to upload image to firebase firebase
This is the error:
Error uploading image or saving product: FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Max retry time for operation exceeded, please try again. (storage/retry-limit-exceeded)
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/olx-clone-18561.appspot.com/o?name=images%2Fproject%20olx.webp net::ERR_FAILED
This is my firebase Config
I tried to upload a file(image) to fire storage and this error occured.

Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question? and Formatting text and code

Well... The details are incomplete.
You should give us the function you used to upload to image!!
there can be multiple possiblities...

Initliase FIrebase correctly



 // firebaseConfig.js
    import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
    import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
    
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
      authDomain: "YOUR_DOMAIN",
      projectId: "..........",
      storageBucket: ".............",
      messagingSenderId: "...........",
      appId: "...........",
      measurementId: "............"
    };
    
    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    const storage = getStorage(app);
    
    export { storage };




You can use this function to upload file in react js



 // FileUpload.js
    import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import { getStorage, ref, uploadBytesResumable, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage';
    import { storage } from './firebaseConfig';
    
    const FileUpload = () => {
      const [file, setFile] = useState(null);
      const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
      const [error, setError] = useState(null);
      const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
    
      const handleFileChange = (e) => {
        setFile(e.target.files[0]);
      };
    
      const handleUpload = () => {
        if (!file) return;
    
        const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${file.name}`);
        const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file);
    
        uploadTask.on('state_changed', 
          (snapshot) => {
            const progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            setProgress(progress);
          }, 
          (error) => {
            setError(error.message);
          }, 
          () => {
            getDownloadURL(uploadTask.snapshot.ref).then((downloadURL) => {
              setUrl(downloadURL);
            });
          }
        );
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          <input type="file" onChange={handleFileChange} />
          <button onClick={handleUpload}>Upload</button>
          <p>Progress: {progress}%</p>
          {error && <p>Error: {error}</p>}
          {url && <p>File available at: <a href={url}>{url}</a></p>}
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default FileUpload;




Check Network Conditions and Retry Limits
internet connection might be culprit.Also, try reducing the file size if it’s too large. You can also adjust the retry settings if needed.

Adjust Firebase Storage Rules
Ensure your Firebase Storage rules allow uploads.


you can reply if the issue persist again.
upvote if my answer helps you.
